# ReferenceError: $ is not defined JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tô tentando criar um rating, mas esse erro persiste no meu código...

js, estou utilizando jquery

```
    $(function(){
    $('.star').on('mouseover', function(){
        var indice = $('.star').index(this);
        $('.star').removeClass('.full');
        for(var i = 0; i<= indice; i++){
            $('.star:eq('+i+')').addClass('full');
        }
    }); 

});
```

html, inclusão do jquery e meu arquivo .js

```
<script src="../js/avaliacao.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apenas alterene a ordem de chamada de arquivo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/avaliacao.js"></script>
```

isso deve resolver, caso não resolva, tente importar outro arquivo do jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Para se tornar realmente um **PROFISSIONAL** na área de desenvolvimento, você precisa entender como funciona a determinada tecnologia. No seu caso você precisa entender como funciona a  estrutura `DOM` do `HTML`!

**O que é um DOM?**

> O Modelo de Objeto de Documento(`DOM`) é uma interface de programação para documentos `HTML`, `XML` e `SVG` . Ele fornece uma representação estruturada do documento como uma árvore. O `DOM` define métodos que permitem acesso à árvore, para que eles possam alterar a estrutura, estilo e conteúdo do documento. O `DOM` fornece uma representação do documento como um grupo estruturado de nós e objetos, possuindo várias propriedades e métodos. Os nós também podem ter manipuladores de eventos que lhe são inerentes, e uma vez que um evento é acionado, os manipuladores de eventos são executados. Essencialmente, ele conecta páginas web a scripts ou linguagens de programação. Embora o `DOM` seja frequentemente acessado usando `JavaScript`, não é uma parte da linguagem `JavaScript`. Ele também pode ser acessado por outras linguagens.

**Exemplo Gráfico:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabendo-se disto, resumidamente em que o browser irá "ler" a estrutura `HTML` linha a linha (de cima para baixo). Adicionando a resposta do **@Theo** o seu **erro está no seguinte:**

```
<script src="../js/avaliacao.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Observe que você inseriu o seu arquivo `.js` **primeiro** e **depois** o `jquery`, então o **browser irá "ler" e "carregar" primeiro o arquivo** `.js`, isto **acarretará no erro o qual você está com dificuldade**. **Para contornar isto é bastante simples, apenas mude a ordem dos** `<script>` **para:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/avaliacao.js"></script>
```